# Finding subset of data where the 'B' in A/B testing is true

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, data-mining

Suppose that I have implemented a referral program in my product, in which I offer rewards to a user whenever one of their referrals uses my product. Say, we reward him with gift/prize 'A'. I am also interested seeing how users react with a different reward 'B'.

To find the significance of either reward I perform an A/B testing. Now, let's say that there is actually no difference from using either reward.

Here is my question:
Suppose, that there is a subset of my users (male, 18 years of age, etc.) in which 'B' actually provides an improvement over 'A' which can be measured from my chosen metric of success. How would I go about finding this particular subset in the data?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fit a mixture model which explicitly allow for heterogeneity in terms of the parameter(s) reflecting difference between A and B. E.g., a latent class regression model, or, a mixed effects model, and then create a model predicting this heterogeneity based on demographics (or, do the two things simultaneously with a hierarchical model specification).

A simpler brute force approach may be a lot easier though: loop through all of your possible demographic variables and categories and perform your AB tests within each group.

Comment: Tim, thank you for your answer! It is very helpful. I was wondering if you might be able to post an example of this or point me to some references so I can read more about it?

Comment: A reference for this general area is Kenneth Train, Discrete Choice Methods with Simulation.